# How do I create dynamic variables inside a loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on a report in PHP where I extract order data, which contains the customer type and order information such as total order value. I need to summarize the data by customer type. On a given day, I don't know ahead of time what customer types will be ordering, and proactively declaring a variable for each possible type seems unnecessary. I know there's another way, I just can't figure it out.

Using the code below, I get the right information - order count and total value by customer type. But I keep receiving "Undefined Index" notices from PHP. I've researched variable variables and while this seems like the solution I'm looking for, I can't figure out how to apply them in an array. Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```php
$array = [
    ["type"=>"WOW","order_no"=>1,"value"=>10],
    ["type"=>"WOW","order_no"=>8,"value"=>20],
    ["type"=>"DLR","order_no"=>10,"value"=>100],
    ["type"=>"DLR","order_no"=>2,"value"=>50],
    ["type"=>"WOW","order_no"=>3, "value"=>25]
];

$totalorders = 0;
$totalvalue = 0;
foreach($array as $k=>$v) 
{
    $custype = isset($v['type']) ? $v['type'] : null;
    $ordervalue = isset($v['value']) ? $v['value'] : null;


    $final[$custype]["orderdollars"] = $final[$custype]["orderdollars"] + $ordervalue;
    $final[$custype]["ordercount"]++;

    $totalorders++;
}
print_r($final);
```

How can I create valid `$custype` variables within the loop to avoid the "Undefined Index" notices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting undefined index errors because `$final` is a two-dimensional array, and you have to create the first dimension (`$custype`) before you can add the second (`orderdollars` and `ordercount`). So you need to add a check that the first dimension exists, and if not, create it, otherwise add to the values:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v) 
{
    $custype = isset($v['type']) ? $v['type'] : null;
    $ordervalue = isset($v['value']) ? $v['value'] : null;

    if (!isset($final[$custype])) {
        $final[$custype] = array('orderdollars' => $ordervalue, 'ordercount' => 1);
    }
    else {
        $final[$custype]["orderdollars"] = $final[$custype]["orderdollars"] + $ordervalue;
        $final[$custype]["ordercount"]++;
    }

    $totalorders++;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [WOW] => Array
        (
            [orderdollars] => 55
            [ordercount] => 3
        )
    [DLR] => Array
        (
            [orderdollars] => 150
            [ordercount] => 2
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/m2Zkd)

**Note**

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with

```
$custype = isset($v['type']) ? $v['type'] : null;
```

but it might be more appropriate to use something like

```
if (!isset($v['type']) || !isset($v['value'])) continue;
```

Comment: Thank you! The purpose of that line was to ensure the `$custype` variable exists before setting it.

Comment: @SpaceAge ok, but if you're just setting the value to `null` if it doesn't exist I'm not sure you'll get the results you want. Perhaps you should set `$custype` to `unknown` and `$value` to `0` in those cases, or as I suggested just skip rows where those values are undefined.

Comment: You're exactly right. When I initialized the variables inside the foreach loop, my values would reset on each iteration. That's what I couldn't figure out. Your advice to initialize the first dimension then second dimension is what removed the errors. Thank you again - really appreciate your help.